# thermal camera app for android?

Tags: android, camera

i want to make thermal camera application for android, but i have no idea how to make it. 
the app well be look like( [example of thermal camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fingersoft.thermalvisioncamera)). please help me how can i make it. and how to start work on it. as there any library are used in this type of app?
i found this code from some where but i can't understand it

```
    NativeYUVDecode.ntialize();
NativeYUVDecode.decodeYUV(Bitmap paramBitmap, int[] paramArrayOfInt, byte[] paramArrayOfByte, int Int1, int Int2, int Int3, int Int4, int Int5, int Int6);
```

will we use a simple camera library in this app?

Comment: You can't.  Notice that the app you linked to said it isn't a real thermal camera-  it fakes it.  You'd need to attack a real thermal camera via bluetooth or USB to do it, or find a model that has a built in one.  If you want to fake one, you could take the cameras image and apply a filter that turns skin tones into yellows and everything else into black.  But it would be a lot of work for a fake.

Comment: as any help to make fake thermal camera

Comment: I'd suggest posing a new question. The answers to that question are quite different to the answers already given to your original question.

Comment: now give answer of this question please i mark them unanswered. help me.

Comment: Are you trying to say that you have posted a new question? If so, it would be convenient to post a link to it here...

Comment: you definetly decompiled the code and the code is written using NDK. whenever you face native keyword in code it means its function is written by c++ or openCv etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid you are way off track on this.

[Thermal cameras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_infrared) use a different part of the light spectrum, one that typical Android devices are not equipped with.

The best you might be able to achieve is the ability to see "near infrared" (the light used by remote controls and CCD security cameras that operate at night, but that is not thermal infrared (the "light" given off by "warm" bodies)

Answer (score 0):

This app is **fake** you cannot have real thermal app without external hardware simile to [IR-Blue](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/andyrawson/ir-blue-thermal-imaging-smartphone-accessory) which uses [Infrared Temperature sensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared_thermometer)